# Putty Window inactive after certain time

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty

I am currently processing on a server. I am using Putty to do this. As I am running multiple processes (8), I am using multiple cores as well.
After a certain time (2-3 days) I get an error saying:

```
PuTTY Network Error: Software caused connection abort.
```

Then my Putty window's status turns to inactive.

Here are my questions:

1. Where does this come from?
2. As most of my files have been processed, is it possible to reactivate Putty in order to continue the processing?

Comment: Sounds like that might be some kind of memory problem. Do you have the latest version of PuTTY? On the server side, can you use TMUX or SCREEN? BYOB is an excellent front end for both. This enables your server session to remain active even when you loose network connections and is strongly recommended for running extended scripts on the server.

Comment: For some reason ssh session was terminated (network error, computer reboot, nat session timeout, firewall session tracking timeout etc.)

Comment: I'd run a ping window in parallel, set it to ping an infinite number of packets. When your putty is interrupted, stop your ping and look at the stats. I'm willing to bet you'll see some packet loss. It sounds like the connection is just being interrupted.

Comment: Your network connection could drop or your DHCP lease address change. Something could've killed the process on the other end, like people say systemd does.  I've only seen it when working from here at home and I have a low grade dsl connection that always gets a new IP on DHCP renew and renews several times a day,  without a pattern...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling KeepAlive in Putty?

http://www.nth-design.com/2010/05/10/using-keepalive-in-putty/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link has broken. A new one: https://cybergav.in/2010/09/11/inactive-putty-sessions/  Short answer:  PuTTy | Settings | Connection | Seconds between keepalives | 60

Answer (score 0):

`tmux` and `screen` are your friends.  Putty will still close, but you'll be able to reconnect and continue what you were doing by re-opening the session, provided you haven't rebooted.